# Which design to choose

Tags: database-design

Suppose I have a website that communicates with a database.

In some page of my site i want to exhibit a list with all the students in my database. There are two kinds of students: regular students, that only participate in regular classes (with attributes such as `student_id, name, email, password`) and special class students, students who participate not only in regular class but also in special extra classes (with all the attributes the regular students have plus an attribute for the `special_class_id`).

In the exhibition of the students on the mentioned page, I want it to exhibit the student differently depending on whether it's a special class student or not.

So i'm thinking here what would be the best database design in order for the code for the exhibition of the students to have the best efficiency/performance.

### Option 1

Two tables on my database, one for all students (with `student_id,name,email,password`)  and one extra for special class students (with `student_id` and a `special_class_id` corresponding to the id of the special class the student participates). Let's name the table with all students by `students` and the other one by `special_students`.

With this option, for the exhibition page, the code would pick each row of the `students` table and display it. It could then check whether that `student_id` was inside any row of the `special_students` table, and if it was, it could exhibit that student differently.

### Option 2

Another option would be having only one table on my database with an extra `special_class_id` column. Then, for regular students this column would have some default value (maybe `0`), and for special class students, this column would have value identifying the `special_class_id`. 
With this option for the exhibition page, it seems to me that the code would be faster since it would query only one table .. but on the other hand, adding this extra column seems a bit sloppy.

Would there be a significant performance advantage on the second option, over the first one, considering an hypothetical situation where the site might have 10 million visitors a day? Can this sloppy extra-column interfere in some way and cause problems?   Is there any other option for the database design?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions are viable and each has different benefits / drawbacks - the best solution depends on your data and how many of your queries need this additional column.

1. Adding the `special_class_id` to the `students` table makes this table "wider", meaning that the performance of all queries against this table will be slightly impacted (even if they don't care about this field). A single INT won't make much difference, but it could start to be an issue if the special students need more columns in the future.
2. Adding a separate table keeps the `students` table clean however at the cost of an additional join, which is likely to be slower whenever you want to retrieve that additional column.

The key is to create views on top of your tables - this allows you to change your tables later should it become necessary. The views you create should tie in with your application requirements, however as an example all of the following views are really easy to build on top of either schema.

- Your application will almost certainly need a list of all students - this view should probably contain only columns for "regular" students (unless your application displays some sort of indicator as to whether or not a student is "special", in this case this view could include that indicator)
- If your application has a separate listing of special students then you can create a separate view which shows only those students with any additional columns required.
- Additionally, should you need to look up the special fields for a specific student you could create an extra view consisting of just the student id and special fields.

This allows you to pick the simplest solution now, and change your tables later should the performance be an issue.

FWIW my gut feel is that option 1 will offer better performance as it avoids a join.

Answer (score 2):

I have read your question, but not your proposed solutions, so I can't be influeced.

So, my ideas is that you can do a table STUDENTS and another table, let's say STUDENT_TYPE.

In STUDENTS, you put a column, ID_STUDENT_TYPE. In this column, you can set, with the ID of STUDENT_TYPE, the type of the single student.

In this way, if you have to insert a new student type, you won't have any problems! ;)
It is an elastic solution!

Comment: With `students` as primary, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the view that you model the structure correctly first and then look at things that will tweak the structure for physical reasons if it becomes necessary.
I say this because many systems start of with the tweaks 'pre-built in', i.e. " I know this will be a problem so I'll construct the data like this from the outset".
Unfortunately this can lead to solutions that don't reflect how the data is in the real world and so when another requirement arises you are constrained by a data structure that is incorrect.

Assuming you are looking at a purely relational scenario then I would suggest STUDENT has a type attribute that is sourced from a STUDENT_TYPE table. This gives the ability to have the type code on the student table but refer to other attributes related to the type itself if necessary later.

Then the STUDENT is also optionally joined to a SPECIAL_CLASS table (implemented via an intersection table) so that details of the special class can be stored and further classes added as and when that becomes a requirement later.

The extra tables and joins should not present a performance problem if the keys and indexes are set up correctly.
If you want to present the tables to the outside world in a different way then you could use views if you wish. Querying against the views, of course, wont make the query any faster but will abstract away some of the underlying structure.

In the unlikely event that performance is a big issue then you could look at making the student table 'wider' by denormalising some of the data from the other columns onto the student table. Just remember that doing so will cost you in terms of maintaining those extra copies of the data.